# Why doesn't a program using BigInteger display anything?

Tags: java, output, pascals-triangle

My program displays Pascal's triangle. For enlarging the portion of the triangle that may be calculated and displayed, I've rewritten the code using BigInteger instead of primitive types.

Here's the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ptrig {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    BigInteger no = BigInteger.valueOf(5);

    // Creating the array
    String doubledim[][] = new String[no.intValue()][];
    BigInteger k;
    for (k = BigInteger.ZERO; k.compareTo(no) < 0; k.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        doubledim[k.intValue()] = new String[k.intValue() + BigInteger.ONE.intValue()];
    }

    // Assigning values
    BigInteger i, j, p, n;
    BigInteger l = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(no) < 0; i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        for (j = BigInteger.ZERO; j.compareTo(i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) < 0; j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            BigInteger m = i.subtract(j);
            if (j.compareTo(m) > 0) {
                for (p = BigInteger.ZERO; p.compareTo(m) < 0; p = p.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                    n = i.subtract(p);
                    l = l.multiply(n);
                }
                doubledim[i.intValue()][j.intValue()] = l.divide(factorial.factmet(m)).toString();
                l = BigInteger.ONE;
            }
            if (m.compareTo(j) > 0) {
                for (p = BigInteger.ZERO; p.compareTo(j) < 0; p = p.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                    n = i.add(p.add(BigInteger.ONE)).subtract(j);
                    l = l.multiply(n);
                }
                doubledim[i.intValue()][j.intValue()] = l.divide(factorial.factmet(j)).toString();
                l = BigInteger.ONE;
            }
            if (m.compareTo(j) == 0) {
                for (p = BigInteger.ZERO; p.compareTo(j) < 0; p = p.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                    n = i.subtract(p);
                    l = l.multiply(n);
                }
                doubledim[i.intValue()][j.intValue()] = l.divide(factorial.factmet(j)).toString();
                l = BigInteger.ONE;
            }
        }
    }

    // Printing
    for (i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(no) < 0; i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        for (j = BigInteger.ZERO; j.compareTo(i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) < 0; j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            System.out.print(doubledim[i.intValue()][j.intValue()] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The problem is it displays nothing. I've read on Stack Overflow I need to convert the array values into strings for that they're displayed, so I did. I've also checked the `System.out.println` statements - they seem to be fine. The error persisted.

The algorithm itself worked fine on a previous version with primitive types.

What's the error here? I did my best to find an answer on the web, I couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see where it doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: Isn't `j < i + 1` the same as `j <= i` when we're talking integers?

Comment: Yep, it's the same. I thought of it as i + 1 when I wrote it for the first time and didn't change then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loops aren't incrementing their indices, and will therefor loop forever.

`i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` doesn't mutate `i`, it [creates a **new** `BigInteger` and returns it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-).  If you want to increment the value of `i`, you need to write `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)`

---

This means that when you try to initialize your array, you're entering an infinite loop, where you re-initialize `doubledim[0]` forever.

e.g.

```
for (k = BigInteger.ZERO; k.compareTo(no) < 0; k.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    doubledim[k.intValue()] = new String[k.intValue() + BigInteger.ONE.intValue()];
}
```

should be

```
for (k = BigInteger.ZERO; k.compareTo(no) < 0; k = k.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    doubledim[k.intValue()] = new String[k.intValue() + BigInteger.ONE.intValue()];
}
```

and you'll need to likewise fix the loops that control the population of data in your arrays, and printing of their data later in your program.

Comment: Thanks. Did that on each loop and double-checked. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: When I fix all the loops and hack up my own `factorial.factmet()` method , your code works fine for me.  I'd recommend triple-checking all your for-loops.

Comment: It's the loop in the method I forgot about. Fixed it, now it works well.